# Android Java: View cannot be applied to ()

Tags: java, android, view

I have a couple of `EditText` that I would like to stay hidden until made visible by one of many methods. To achieve this I was hoping to make my controls visible in it's own public void and call it back.

```
    public void showControls(View view) {
            EditText showV = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.vedit);
            EditText showH = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hedit);

            showH.setVisability(view.VISABLE);
            showV.setVisability(view.VISABLE);
    }


    //calling on showControls
    public void onMethodOne (View view) {
        showControls();
    }
```

My output reads:

```
com.rayman.raysgame.MainActivity.showControls(android.view.View) in com.rayman.raysgame.MainActivity cannot be applied to ()
```

I don't really understand the output, so I am not sure how am I screwing up the code. I'd like to understand my mistake.

Comment: `showH.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` spelling wrong

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `showControls` to take a `View` as an argument, but you're calling it with no arguments. You might want to change:

```
showControls();
```

to:

```
showControls(view);
```

However, I don't see that you are using the view itself in `showControls`. (You will also need to change the spelling of `view.VISABLE` to `view.VISIBLE` in that method.)

Comment: I can understand the reason for that. The output now reads: 'Unknown variable or field "view"' though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `showControls(view);` instead of `showControls();` as your method takes a `View` as an argument

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the correct function by adding its argument `showControls(View view)`. Its a very basic in programming language although.

And you have to call the findViewById by a proper way. It should be a instance of `view`.

Use this:

```
public void showControls(View view) {
      EditText showV = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.vedit);
      EditText showH = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.hedit);

      showH.setVisability(view.VISIBLE);
      showV.setVisability(view.VISIBLE);
}


//calling on showControls
public void onMethodOne (View view) {
     showControls(view);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code

```
showH.setVisability(view.VISABLE);
showV.setVisability(view.VISABLE);
```

to

```
showH.setVisability(View.VISIBLE);
showV.setVisability(View.VISIBLE);
```